# Alamofire - Allow redirecting again

Tags: swift, alamofire, swift4

I have POST request where, I had to disallow redirecting - I prevented redirecting with these lines of code:

```
let delegate = Alamofire.SessionManager.default.delegate
delegate.taskWillPerformHTTPRedirection = {(_, _, _, _) -> URLRequest? in
    return nil
}
```

In my next POST request I want to allow redirecting, but I don't know how to achieve this. 
**How to allow redirecting**, when I prevented redirecting before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
// Restore to original behaviour
let delegate = Alamofire.SessionManager.default.delegate
delegate.taskWillPerformHTTPRedirection = nil
```

Thanks to https://nacho4d-nacho4d.blogspot.com/2017/08/preventing-alamofire-redirect.html

Answer (score 1):

Instead of just returning `nil` from the closure, you'll need to check which request is being made to determine whether you want to redirect.